# LibGDX: move and then stop box2d immediately

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I'm working on a project in LibGDX.
It's a 2d platform game. you can say it's like Super Mario.

So this is how i move my player to the right:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
    player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
}
```

When i leave the key, the player is still moving a bit. (it's still have "Linear Impulse" force on his physical body i think).

How can i make it stop?

My question could be simple as:
What is the best way to move a physical body on LibGDX in one direction while holding a key. and when i leave the key, the player stops immediately.

***bdw -  I have tryied with "setTransform" and it's making issues when the body is touching other objects - plus the sahpe come "before" the rest of the game in the screen (you can see it on debug)***

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is OK. I would also recommend to set the max speed of your body:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x < maxSpeed)
    player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
}
```

Stop your body immediately by using the `setLinearVelocity` method.:

```
player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(0f, 0f);
```

Comment: @icarumbas this is how i set it: pastebin.com/Kjng1uEf And while pressing a movement key, the player is running and stopping, running and stoping.. how do i fix that?

Comment: @ROSA move this: `player2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 12.00f` and this `player2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -12.00f` inside if statement. I mean delete `&&` and create another `if`

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for correcting my grammar. Working on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. it's working as i want it to work.

Comment: @ROSA glad that my answer helped you.